Why has memtest stuck/froze on Windows 10 64 bit UEFI?
I left memtest running for a few hours but came back to this:

The cursor at the bottom left blinks but that's about it. Pressing the keys like Esc and Space do nothing.

Since it failed after 19m55s, it would be easy to re-run it and see if it behaves the same; that would be my first try.
